# How to construct all Indecomposable representations of a quiver (up to isomorphism)?

Tags: representation-theory

Can you give me a sketch of how to Construct all (up to isomorphism) indecomposable representations of a quiver of type $E_{6}$ and $D_{6}$. Perhaps using Gabriel theorem.

Thank you

Comment: This is explained in pretty much all textbooks which deal with the subject; the standard way to do it is using Auslander-Reiten theory, in the form of the "knitting algorithm". The best plan would be for you to browse one.

Comment: Ok thank you. Could you please give me the references of the textbooks?

Comment: The book by Assem, Skowronski and Simson, for example.